# Looking for ideas to video sync with a document with HTML 5 and Webvtt

Tags: javascript, html5-video, webvtt

I'm just started on a new project. I am working with a court transcript and a video deposition. I would like to create a web player that sync's the transcript file with the video. I am trying to figure out where to start with this. I already have converted the transcript to Webvtt and I was thinking I could leverage the Webvtt with the output by reading the events on the viewer to sync with the lines of the transcript.

I want to do something similar to this:
[Sync Deposition Transcript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bsyj7tj25Ys)

I am think I would take the Webvtt data and put them in an unordered list. Then use the timeupdate event to get the video time to change the scroll position of the document.

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.ontimeupdate = function() {myFunction()};
```

I'm working on the prototype now. But I wanted to know if this is right way to go or is there something out there that already can do part of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you pull the captions through the TextTrackCueList list. In the simplest example, loop through the cues collection to get your VTT captions:

```
const video = document.getElementById('video')
const track = video.textTracks[0]
// loop through track.cues to get entire VTT data
// loop through track.activeCues to get the cues that should be highlighted

track.oncuechange = function (){
 // update highlights
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [a W3C blog](http://people.w3.org/%7Edom/archives/2009/02/the-beauty-of-htmlmediaelement/) which says that we can include text content, slide or hyperlink table of index that points to certain part of the video synced, like [this](https://media.w3.org/2009/02/presentation-viewer-screencast.ogv). In that video it is closed caption (cc). But I think this technique can be used for creating scrollable transcript as well. We'd have to use  javascript as well.